# Django settings module is defined but still not working

Tags: python, django, django-models

What I am essentially trying to do is generate problems and connect those problems to a model, The generation part worked perfectly but until I tried to update the generated values to a model, I keep getting the error

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting INSTALLED_APPS, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable
 DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.
```

I've tried calling `settings.configure()` in `wsgi.py` and `manage.py` but no luck. I already have `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` defined in `wsgi.py` and even in the script, I have it defined as well using. I also tried adding the variable using shell and used Django-admin but still had no luck

```
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'QuickChemistry.settings')
```

Here is a picture of my project tree:

[image]

I believe that the error is coming from the actual script itself which was working perfectly before, but when I tried to add it to a model is when this error occurred. This error happens whenever I run `django_compounds.py`.

Here is the `django_compounds.py` file in a hastebin since it is fairly long https://www.toptal.com/developers/hastebin/umesotedir.py

Comment: What does "I tried to update the generated values to a model" mean? _Specifically_, what are you doing to get this error? Please read [ask].

Comment: And please don't post links to code off-site. Include all relevant information _here_, directly in the question.

Comment: @Chris I have a Django called Model "problem". The script is supposed to populate that model through it's generated results and display It through template tagging.  The result generation was working fine, but populating the model is where I am reaching this error.

Comment: I think you cannot access a Django environment from a random script like this. Create a proper [management command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/custom-management-commands/) in the `quickapp` app and run it through `manage.py`.

Comment: I'll look into management command but I've done this exact same process with a different script but different content and had no trouble getting the task done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it was a problem with the script file and believe it or not it was a super simple fix. I was trying to import the Model before even calling the `os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'QuickChemistry.settings')`

Instead of doing:

```
from quickapp.models import ChemProblems
import os
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE",'QuickChemistry.settings')

import django
django.setup()

import random
import csv
```

I called the import AFTER I called the settings file like this

```
import os
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE",'QuickChemistry.settings')

import django
django.setup()

import random
import csv

from quickapp.models import ChemProblems # Call the import AFTER
```